# How to handle special character in squlite data base phone gap

Tags: sqlite, mysqli, cordova

How to handle special character in squlite data base phone gap .Actually whenever user enter special  character in db my application crash.How to handle that .I want to user able to enter special character but while inserting it changes to other text .And while reading reconvert it into same special character .Is this possible . Here is my code

```
var db = "";
//will create database Dummy_DB or open it

//function will be called when device ready
function onDeviceReady() {


    db = window.openDatabase("Casepad", "1.0", "Casepad", 200000);
 //db.delete("DROP TABLE CaseTable", null, null);
    if (window.localStorage.getItem("isAddSomeData") == "yes") {

        db.transaction(getallTableData, errorCB);


    }    
}

function insertData() {
    db.transaction(createTable, errorCB, afterSuccessTableCreation);
}

//create table and insert some record
function createTable(tx) {
    tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS CaseTable (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, CaseName  VARCHAR(100) unique NOT NULL ,CaseDate INTEGER ,TextArea VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL)');

    tx.executeSql('INSERT OR IGNORE INTO CaseTable(CaseName,CaseDate,TextArea) VALUES ("' + $('.caseName_h').val() + '", "' + $('.caseDate_h').val() + '","' + $('.caseTextArea_h').val() + '")');


}
//function will be called when an error occurred
function errorCB(err) {
    navigator.notification.alert("Error processing SQL: " + err.code);
}

//function will be called when process succeed
function afterSuccessTableCreation() {
    console.log("success!");
    db.transaction(getallTableData, errorCB);
}



//select all from SoccerPlayer
function getallTableData(tx) {
    // tx.executeSql("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS a");       
    tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM CaseTable', [], querySuccess, errorCB);
}



function querySuccess(tx, result) {


    var len = result.rows.length;
    var countDoument=0
    $('#folderData').empty();
    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {

    currentTableName=result.rows.item(i).CaseName;

     countElements(currentTableName, function(i) {
      return function(result_count) {
        countDoument = result_count; // here it count value 

       $('#folderData').append(
            '<li class="caseRowClick" id="' + result.rows.item(i).id + '" data-rel="popup" data-position-to="window">' + '<a href="#">' + '<img src="img/Blue-Folder.png">' + '<h2>' + result.rows.item(i).CaseName  + '</h2>' + '<p>' + result.rows.item(i).TextArea + '</p>' + '<p>' + result.rows.item(i).CaseDate + '</p>' +'<span class="ui-li-count">' + countDoument + '</span>'+  '</a>' +
            '<span class="ctrl togg"><fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal" data-mini="true" ><button class="edit button_design">Edit</button><button class="del button_design">Delete</button></fieldset><span>' + '</li>'
        );
           $('#folderData').listview('refresh');

      };

    }(i));


}


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use parameters, then you do not need to bother with conversions:

```
tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO Tab(Name, Date) VALUES(?,?)',
              [$('.caseName_h').val(),
               $('.caseDate_h').val()]);
```

Comment: so it will take the special character  in data base..?

Comment: Yes, and must NEVER merge user typed text in your SQL statement. This is SQL security basics.